# Undefined type 'Stripe\StripeClient' while integrating Stripe with my php project

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Pardon me if this has been asked already. I am a beginner trying to integrate stripe payment gateway in my PHP sample project. I installed stripe API using composer from [stripe github page](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php).    using `composer require stripe/stripe-php` in my project directory.  `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`  is working just fine. but simple usage code is not working properly

```
 $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('my secret key would be here');
    $customer = $stripe->customers->create([
        'description' => 'example customer',
        'email' => 'email@example.com',
        'payment_method' => 'pm_card_visa',
    ]);
    echo $customer;
```

1. cURL
2. JSON
3. mbstring
   are already installed and available in my system.

[image]

I tried solution described in [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63142189/trying-to-setup-stripe-api-with-php-and-getting-an-error-saying-undefined-type)

but no positive results appeared. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
require_once('/stripe-php-master/init.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('stripe_sectet_key');


$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
    'description' => 'example customer',
    'email' => 'email@example.com',
    'payment_method' => 'pm_card_visa',
]);

echo $customer;
```

Comment: I removed all the files i installed using composure and manually added stripe library and its working now, thanks for the help!

Comment: just download https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php and add inside your root folder and make sure require_once path correctly